# How to configure opencv 2.3 with qt creator to use the stock mingw compiler from qt sdk installation

Tags: opencv, qt-creator

Sorry for asking a question thats already asked by some..
But even after many days of search and tries i couldnt make opencv work with qt creator..
Hope any body can give me the steps for doing so.

Last time i tried by calling just one opencv specific function to check if it compiles correctly, but its giving some errors which are due to linking problems, i have built the opencv library using my mingw compiler from code blocks as described in some of the tutorials, even that didnt work.

I'm getting this error

> :-1: error: cannot find -lopencv_core
>
> :-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

My pro file looks as follows

QT       += core

TARGET = Open_cv_integration

CONFIG   += console

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

LIBS += "C:/opencv2.2MinGW/lib/libopencv_core231.dll.a"

LIBS += -lm -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_video -lopencv_imgproc

Comment: actually this is working for me

INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv2.2MinGW/include

LIBS += C:/opencv2.2MinGW/bin/*.dll

and i had to copy all dll's required for me to the system32 directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
LIBS += \
  -LD:\your lib directory\ -llibopencv_highgui231 \
INCLUDEPATH += \
   D:/your include dir/include/
```

should work for you. 
QtCreator has very good help, and there is said how to add lib to project.